# How do I extract the UUID for a specific VM and Group with awk?

Tags: awk

I am using `vboxmanage list -l vms` and I want to extract the UUID for a specific machine by giving the `Name` and `Groups` values.

```
Name:                        vm2
Groups:                      /C05Lab1
Guest OS:                    Oracle (64-bit)
UUID:                        54c233e8-3d5b-46bb-9a21-a8946ffa7d76
Config file:                 C:\Users\Bianca\VirtualBox VMs\C05Lab1\vm2\vm2.vbox
Snapshot folder:             C:\Users\Bianca\VirtualBox VMs\C05Lab1\vm2\Snapshots
Log folder:                  C:\Users\Bianca\VirtualBox VMs\C05Lab1\vm2\Logs
Hardware UUID:               54c233e8-3d5b-46bb-9a21-a8946ffa7d76
```

I got to:

```
vboxmanage list -l vms | awk '$1=="UUID:"{uid=$2} /Name: *vm2/{print uid}'
```

It at least lists an uuid, but not the right one(it prints the uuid of the machine before it) and I have no idea how to check for the `Groups` value because it starts with a `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
vboxmanage list -l vms | 
awk -v name="vm2" -v group="C05Lab1" '
/^Name:/{
  foundName=foundGroup=""
  if($2==name){ foundName=1 }
  next
}
/^Groups:/ && $2==group{
  foundGroup=1
  next
}
/^UUID:/ && foundName && foundGroup{
  print
  foundName=foundGroup=""
}'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation here.

```
vboxmanage list -l vms |               ##Running command vboxmanage list -l vms and sending its Output to awk as an input.
awk -v name="vm2" -v group="C05Lab1" ' ##Starting awk command from here and setting name to vm2 and group to C05Lab1 here.
/^Name:/{                              ##Checking condition if line starts with Name: then do following.
  foundName=foundGroup=""              ##Nullifying foundName and foundGroup here.
  if($2==name){ foundName=1 }          ##Checking condition if 2nd field is name then set foundName to 1 here.
  next                                 ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/^Groups:/ && $2==group{               ##Checking condition if line starts from Groups: and 2nd field is group then do following.
  foundGroup=1                         ##Setting foundGroup to 1 here.
  next                                 ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/^UUID:/ && foundName && foundGroup{   ##Checking condition if line starts from UUID: and foundName and foundGroup are set then do following.
  print                                ##Printing currnet line here.
  foundName=foundGroup=""              ##Nullifying foundName and foundGroup here.
}'
```

---

EDIT by Ed Morton to show an alternative approach to commenting the code, i.e. commenting to say **why** we're doing things instead of **what** we're doing:

```
vboxmanage list -l vms |
awk -v name="vm2" -v group="C05Lab1" ' # Set variables to contain the Name: and Groups: values we want to find in the input
/^Name:/{                              # We assume that every record starts with Name: and so we clear the
  foundName=foundGroup=""              # foundName and foundGroup flags here so that when we hit the UUID:
                                       # line later they arent still set from reading the previous record.
  if($2==name){ foundName=1 }          # If the current value of the Name: matches the target value stored in
                                       # our "name" variable then set the flag to indicate that so when we test
                                       # it on our UUID: line we know we found the target name.
  next
}
/^Groups:/ && $2==group{               # If the current value of the Group: matches the target value stored in
  foundGroup=1                         # our "group" variable then set the flag to indicate that so when we test
                                       # it on our UUID: line we know we found the target group.
  next
}
/^UUID:/ && foundName && foundGroup{   # Were on the UUID: line from the input so if we had previously found
  print                                # our target "name" and "group" as indicated by the 2 flags we set earlier
                                       # then we output the current line which contains the UUID.
  foundName=foundGroup=""              # Clear foundName and foundGroup flags here to ensure that when we hit the UUID:
                                       # line for the next record they arent still set from reading the current record
}'
```

Comment: Hello! When running this I got `-v: command not found`, so I tried replacing that using `BEGIN` this way: ` vboxmanage list -l vms | 
awk 'BEGIN {name="vm2" && -v group="C05lab1"}
/^Name:/{
  foundName=foundGroup=""
  if($2==name){ foundName=1 }
  next
}
/^Groups:/ && $2==group{
  foundGroup=1
  next
}
/^UUID:/ && foundName && foundGroup{
  print
  foundName=foundGroup=""
}' `

Comment: @Bianca-ElenaDuduman, sorry there was a typo, could you please check my updated one now and let me know?

Comment: Please read the answers at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1/comments-are-a-code-smell as they contain many examples and explanations of what I've been trying to tell you about why many of your comments would be best left out of your code and how you should be writing comments instead. The fundamental principle is that comments should explain why the code does what it does, not what it does, but almost all of your comments just state what the code does, not why it does it.

Comment: And yes, I know people thank you for adding comments, but that's just a knee-jerk reaction to seeing comments and they'd thank you far more for and benefit far more from explanatory comments.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure sir, I thank you for your views and guidance here, with all respect this is the way I like to write comments because I think it could be helpful for those who doesn't know programing(but know logic), again I don't want to debate on it, we both know we are trying to help people in our own way. By the way I did started writing small explanations in few posts if you would have notice, thank you.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from but writing `foundGroup=1` and then adding a comment of `Setting foundGroup to 1 here.` helps absolutely no-one and your code will be much clearer without it. I promise you, there is a better way to comment code. I hope you don't mind but rather than just waving my arms around trying to describe the better way of commenting I updated your question to show the right way to comment your code. Note that by adding those comments I uncovered some redundancy in the code `foundName=foundGroup=""` shouldn''t be happening in 2 different places.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you have tag-value pairs in your input it's best to first create an array to hold those values indexed by their tags (aka keys aka names), e.g. `f[]` below, and then you can just access the values by their tags to easily compare, print, modify, reorder, etc. as you like:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
    f[tag] = val
}
(tag == "UUID") && (f["Name"] == name) && (f["Groups"] == groups) {
    print val
}
```

```
$ awk -v name='vm2' -v groups='/C05Lab1' -f tst.awk file
54c233e8-3d5b-46bb-9a21-a8946ffa7d76
```